# How to resolve error : Cannot convert from 'OSamp::Weapon' to 'OSamp::Weapon' in C++ CLR

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm getting weird error that says can't convert a type to itself !
Can anyone tell me what is wrong here ! ?

```
public ref class Weapon{

private :
    int Slot_, Id_, Ammo_;
    System::String^ Name_;

public :
    Weapon(EWeapons Id, int Ammo) : Id_((int)Id), Ammo_(Ammo){}
    Weapon(int Id, int Ammo) : Id_(Id), Ammo_(Ammo){}

//other part of code...
}

property OSamp::Weapon Weapon{
    OSamp::Weapon get(){
        return OSamp::Weapon(1, 1000);
// error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'OSamp::Weapon' to 'OSamp::Weapon'
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to return a reference there. OSamp::Weapon^

Comment: @YochaiTimmer No, I'm amusing this as a struct which has properties just like C#.

Comment: Then make it a value class. ref classes are referenced classes.

Comment: Yes now works. I could accept this solution if you post it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a **[value class](http://www.drdobbs.com/ccli-value-class-types/184401955)** instead of a reference class.

Value classes can be passed by value and don't need to be passesd by reference pointer.

Comment: @Dan the op said "I'm amusing this as a struct which has properties" which is what you would use a value struct for.